# C programming: String manipulation

Tags: c, arrays, string

Let's say I have:-

```
char Data[1000];
```

After doing some data extraction and manipulation, passing it around into helper functions (as `char * Data`), I am doing the following to remove a leading `','` from the data:-

```
if (Data[0] == ',') Data++;
```

And this works like a charm.

However as I was building my code up, I started using `struct`, instead of singular variables.

So now I have this:-

```
struct BigData
{
   char Data[1000];
}
```

I still manipulate it and pass it along and everything works fine until I try to remove the leading ','. My above methodology doesn't work as follows:-

```
if (_bigData.Data[0] == ',') _bigData.Data++;
```

for obvious reasons. So I decided to create a temp `char` array as follows:-

```
char temp[1000];
strcpy(temp, _bigData.Data);
if(temp[0] == ',') temp++;
```

Can anyone explain to me why this doesn't work?

I am just now beginning to code in C (coming from C# where such string manipulations are a very surface level procedure).

Comment: You comparisons should be `==` to compare `temp[0]` and `','`. `=` is the assignment operator. Does this give you the results you expect?

Comment: `Data++;`? That should not compile because `Data` is an array name.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part, I was just writing pseudo code...well that does compile and give me the required result. here is what I found:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295754/how-to-remove-first-character-from-c-string

Comment: You must define `char *temptr = temp` or whatever and manipulate that instead.

Comment: `char Data[1000]; ... if (Data[0] == ',') Data++;` cannot "work like a charm". It's a syntax error.

Comment: @WeatherVane - from the OP's text: "...passing it around into helper functions (as `char * Data`)" - I can only assume the line he's quoting is in said-function, not shortly after that var decl. It is the only path i see where this "works" at all.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes I see. Problem with duplicated names and code fragments!

Comment: @WeatherVane I suspect so as well.

Comment: you might use something similar to: `if ( ',' == Data[0]) { memmove( Data, Data+1 ); }`  Which has advantages.  1) `memmove()` allows overlapping copies,  2) does not require an additional stack usage 3) permanently removes any leading comma.   Notice the literal ',' is on the left size so an oops like using `=` rather than `==` will be caught by the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incrementing a pointer is OK.  `Data` is a *pointer*.

```
// After doing some data extraction and manipulation, 
// passing it around into helper functions (as char * Data), 
// I am doing the following to remove a leading ',' from the data:-
void helper_function(char *Data) {
  if (Data[0] == ',') Data++;
  ...
```

Incrementing an *array* is not legal C syntax.  `temp[]` is an *array*.

```
char temp[1000];
...
if(temp[0] == ',') temp++;  // error
```

---

Perhaps OP could assign the array to a pointer and then increment the *pointer* to meet code's objective.

```
char temp[1000];
char *p = temp;
...
if(p[0] == ',') p++;  // OK
```

> ..., an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object ...  C11dr §6.3.2.1 3

Comment: Yeah, though I always prefer/recommend `*ptr = &arr[0]` in this situation as it's completely clear about what it's doing, no need to squint at it for a few seconds :)

Answer (score -3):

Declare `temp` like this:

```
char *temp[1000]
```

then try this:

```
int index = 0;
while(temp[index] != '\0')         //check if temp[index] is still valid
{
    if (temp[index] == ',')
    {
        index++;
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: ...because a lot of people, for no apparent reason, default to using postfix operators even when they don't need the pre-operator value? but anyway - `else break` lolwut, this invalidates the purpose of using a loop. also, you're declaring an array of pointers, not chars... oh, my mistake, `chat`s, whatever those are... @Philo, the postfix is the least of the problems here!

Comment: sure I understand. That was not very well written. I guess I could just use memmove.... but I thought the other was kinda slick.

Comment: well, `strncpy` is often better for strings as it won't copy past the null, assuming you don't care about anything thereafter in the buffer. if you do, `memcpy` is better; `memmove` is only needed if the ranges might overlap. **however**, i don't see why you need a copy at all...? just declare a pointer to the start of your buffer, increment past the comma, and pass the result to whatever manipulation/printing awaits it. that's _effectively_ what you did with the raw `char[]`, but the key is to use a real pointer, not an `arrayElement[0]` that _happens, in certain cases,_ to decay to a pointer

Comment: I tried doing it with a pointer as:- char *temp[1000]... then do strcpy where I get the value from the struct into the temp...and then perform the ++ manipulation.. it didn't work for me.. I am sure I am not understanding this yet

Comment: @underscore_d `strcpy` will not copy past the terminator either. What `strncpy` adds is the size of the target buffer. *That* is what it won't copy past.

Comment: You know `temp[index]` is `char*`, not `char`, *right* ? The first line in this answer declares an array of one-thousand `char *` (i.e. `char` *pointers*).

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks: my C is rusty. :) Would mod up the comment but I'm all voted out for the day. I  was comparing `str[n]cpy` to the `mem` functions, rather than comparing the `str` siblings. Couldn't quite remember the difference but _did_ remember the `n` version being safer, so I defaulted to recommending that. In retrospect, the reason is obvious, since that's the only way I can think of to gain safety, heh.

Comment: this line: `char *temp[1000]` is declaring an array of 1000 pointers to character, That is not what is needed