# How to remove first character from const char* in C language code

Tags: c, string, c-strings

Can anyone please help me? I need to remove the first character from a `const char *` in C.

For example, `const char * contents` contains a `'x'` character as the first character in the array. I need to detect and eliminate this character, modifying the original variable after its been "sanitized".

Can anyone suggest how to achieve it? I'm completely new to C (though I know Java), and just can't seem to figure it out.

`Note:` I already referred to these, and still not able to figure out:
[How to remove first character from C-string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295754/how-to-remove-first-character-from-c-string) - this tell how to remove when the input is char * contents
AND
[Difference between char* and const char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834067/difference-between-char-and-const-char)
it mentions that const char* is a mutable pointer but points to immutable character/string

What I `tried` below it works, but why it works?(it should not able to modify the immutable char array contents value "xup")

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char input[4] = "xup";
    removeLeadingX(input);

    return 0;
}

int removeLeadingX(const char * contents)
{
         //this if condition is something I have to add
         //can't modify other code (ex: the method receives const char * only)
         if(contents[0] == 'x'){
            contents++;
        }
            printf(contents);//up - why immutable string "xup" updated to "up"?
            return 0;

}
```

Comment: You correctly recognized that a `const char*` does not allow modifying the content. But if you move the pointer to point to second character you will get a similar result.

Comment: If you intent to modify strings, why do you use `const char*` in first place?

Comment: If the string is allocated dynamically through `malloc()` you should additionally keep the original pointer around, because the moved pointer can't be used to `free()` the string.

Comment: Check [this out](https://godbolt.org/z/4oTjx34z6)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove first character from C-string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295754/how-to-remove-first-character-from-c-string)

Comment: @Gerhardh I have to live with the existing code(more logic) and thats why ```const char*```

Comment: @ThisaruG yes, it answers my question, but partially (even I mentioned it in the post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove anything from the const char object.

1. You need to make a copy of the string and then modify and use the copy

```
const char *original = "Hello world!";

char *copy = strdup(original);

copy[strlen(copy) - 1] = 0;  //removing `!`
```

2. You can modify the pointer to reference other element of the string. But you lose the original pointer and actually do not remove anything from the string.

```
    const char *original = "Hello world!";
    original = strchr(original, 'w');
    printf("%s\n", original);
```

> What I tried below it works, but why it works?(it should not able to
> modify the immutable char array contents)

In your example you modify the pointer not the object referenced by the pointer. It is OK.

If you declare this function as

```
void removeLeadingX(const char * const contents)
```

the pointer will also be `const` and your code will not compile.

Comment: thnx 0________ !!!

can you please elaborate a little more on this comment
"In your example you modify the pointer not the object referenced by the pointer. It is OK."

Comment: @lowLatency do you know what pointers are? When you add one to pointer it simply points the next character in the string. String is not affected

Comment: @lowLatency `contents` in your function is a local variable. When the function is called, the address of the array is copied down into this local variable. Therefore modifying `contents` with ++ will only affect the local copy, not the original variable on the caller-side. Furthermore you can only use ++ on pointers, not on arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to remove the leading character, or simply ignore it.

Here's an example of what the function is doing (simply changing the pointer)

```
int main() {
    char input[4] = "xup";

    char *p = input;

    printf( "advance\n" );
    p = p + 1;
    printf( "input: '%s'\n", input );
    printf( "p: '%s'\n", p );

    printf( "retreat\n" );
    p = p - 1;
    printf( "input: '%s'\n", input );
    printf( "p: '%s'\n", p );

    printf( "nothing has been removed or shifted except the pointer 'p'\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
advance
input: 'xup'
p: 'up'
retreat
input: 'xup'
p: 'xup'
nothing has been removed or shifted except the pointer 'p'
```

Answer (score 1):

The function declaration `int removeLeadingX(const char * contents)` doesn't make any sense. Either the function should modify the passed string "in place", in which case the function should be:

```
void removeLeadingX (char* contents)
```

Or the function should store a modified copy of the original (immutable) string somewhere, in which case the function could be:

```
void removeLeadingX (char* new_str, const char* old_str)
```

These could be implemented as:

```c
void removeLeadingX (char* contents)
{
  if(contents[0]) == 'x')
    memmove(&contents[0], &contents[1], 1);
}
```

Or:

```c
void removeLeadingX (char* new_str, const char* old_str)
{
  if(old_str[0] == 'x')
  {
    // assuming new_str points at a caller-allocated array:
    strcpy(new_str, &old_str[1]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the original object in `main` is not `const`, you can modify the array using a dirty trick to avoid warnings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int removeLeadingX(const char *contents)
{
    if (contents[0] == 'x')
    {
        union {const char *constant; char *not_constant;} dummy = {contents};

        memmove(dummy.not_constant, contents + 1, strlen(contents));
    }
    printf("%s\n", contents);
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char input[4] = "xup";

    removeLeadingX(input);
    return 0;
}
```